# Escape characters in sed output filename

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script in which I invoke sed to perform some manipulations on a text files contents. However I have noticed that if the filepath contains certain characters they are interpreted by sed as an instruction instead of a literal string. How can I escape these characters from the bash script?

The part of the script in question (where $I is actually declared as an increment used inside a loop):

```
$I=0
OUTPUT=folder/m_Filename"$I".h
sed -i '1s;^;TEXT_TO_PREPEND;' "$OUTPUT"
```

which throws:

```
sed: 1: "{folder/m_Filename0.h}": invalid command code m
```

Running the script on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Now that you've corrected the typo, I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: does `sed -i '1s;^;TEXT_TO_PREPEND;' folder/m_Filename0.h` work?

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech I can actually reproduce it literally with the edit posted above. I'm on OS X El Capitan just to be more precise.

Comment: @spasic: sadly, no...

Comment: related: [in-place editing sed documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201609081443004729825)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some versions of sed require that you specify a suffix after the `-i` option, which will be used to create a backup of the file you have overwritten:

```
sed -i '.bak' '1s;^;TEXT_TO_PREPEND;' "$OUTPUT"
```

Without this, it's possible that the sed command is being interpreted as the backup suffix, in turn causing the filename to be interpreted as the sed command.

If you really don't want a backup to be created, then you can pass an empty string `-i ''`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that one, I have updated the original description as it was an unfortunate typo when I was renaming the contents. It still gives the same error though...

Comment: The empty string '' passed to the -i parameter did the trick! I was under the assumption that by not specifying any value (implied by the space) was doing the equivalent. Thanks Tom!